# How to use a custom Button instead of ExpanderButton

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I've used the `TreeView` control for a project and it's been really useful for me! You've saved a lot of hard work, so I wanted to thank you in the first place :)

I need to fill a `TreeView` using a custom `UserControl` which, among other fields, has a `button` that must perform as the `ExpanderButton`.

Here's the `DataTemplate` from which the TreeView page is filled:

```
  <DataTemplate
                    x:Key="TreeViewItemTemplate">
                    <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                        <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" />
                    </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>

                    <Grid>
                        <components:VideoSessions Title="{Binding Title}"
                                                  Start="{Binding Start}"
                                                  End="{Binding End}"
                                                  Status="{Binding Status}"
                                                  HasHighlights="{Binding HasHighlights}"/>
                    </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

How could I bind the behavior of the `ExpanderButton` to my control?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you want your TreeViewItems to expand/collapse?

Comment: Could you sketch a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TreeView`](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs) control has an `IsExpandedBindingPath` property ([as used in here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.Debugging.UWP/Views/VisualTreeView.xaml)) that you could use to bind the expanded state of the `TreeViewItems` to your backing tree node models. You could then `TwoWay`-bind the toggle state of your `ExpanderButton` to that same property on the tree node model.